# $A \subset C$ implies $A \cap C \subset B \cap C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help with proving this set of expressions in boolean algebra:

$$
A \subset B \implies A \cap C \subset B \cap C
$$

I tried to solve it like this:
$$
A \subset B \implies A \cap C \subset B \cap C\\
\lnot(A\lor B) \lor (\lnot(A\land B))\lor (B\land C)\\
(\lnot A\land\lnot B) \lor (\lnot A\lor \lnot B) \lor (B\land C)\\
...
$$
but it gets too complicated, and I am not sure I get the correct result.

I'd like to have some clue on how to solve it.

Comment: The title makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try element chasing:

$A \subset B$ means, by definition, $$\begin{align}(x \in A \rightarrow x\in B) & \implies [(x \in A \land x \in C) \rightarrow (x \in B \land x \in C)] \\ \\ & \iff (x \in A\cap C \rightarrow x \in B\cap C)\end{align}$$

And this means $A\cap C \subset B\cap C$.

Comment: You really LOVE logic, Amy.

Comment: @Babak I'm about 35 upvotes from a gold badge in logic! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: I agree with Babak, u r excellent at these! =1

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fact that $A \cap C \subset C$ and because $A \cap C \subset A$ and $A \subset B$, then $A \cap C \subset B$.

You asked for a clue, so I assume you don't want the entire answer...